# Why is this value not passing between my ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm coding a multi-step sign-up flow, but cannot get the cell labels to pass between each viewcontroller.

Here is the code from the first viewController:

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
var userGoalOptions = ["Lose Fat","Gain Muscle", "Be Awesome"]
var selectedGoal: String = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "What Is Your Goal?"

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1")! as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = userGoalOptions[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return userGoalOptions.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!

    selectedGoal = currentCell.textLabel!.text!

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "secondSeque") {

            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondVC

            vc.userGoal = selectedGoal       
    }
}
```

The segue (secondSegue) is connected to the table view cell in Interface Builder

In my destination viewcontroller (vc) I have an empty userGoal variable, but when I try to print the contents it returns nothing.

I know variations of this question have been asked numerous times, but I can't seem to find (or maybe understand) what I'm messing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the segue is connected to the table view cell in Interface Builder the cell is passed as the `sender` parameter in `prepareForSegue`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "secondSeque") {
        let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)!
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondVC

        vc.userGoal = userGoalOptions[selectedIndexPath.row]       
}
```

In this case `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not needed and can be deleted.

---

Apart from that it is always the better way to retrieve the data from the model (`userGoalOptions`) than from the view (the table view cell) for example

## **Do**

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
selectedGoal = userGoalOptions[indexPath.row]
```

## **Do not**

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!
selectedGoal = currentCell.textLabel!.text!
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The segue is connected to the tableviewcell in interface builder, and as I have removed didSelectRowAtIndexPath. However, the content of the label is still not passing to the second view.

I have updated the question to add in your assumption

Comment: Set breakpoints or insert `print` lines to figure out if the methods are called and to watch the variables. It might be a typo. Check the segue identifier in Interface Builder. Maybe it's `secondSegue` rather than `secondSeque`

Comment: Segue !== seque. I have no idea how you figured that out, but THANK YOU. I feel like such a fool. You are a jedi.

Answer (score 1):

The `prepareForSegue` Should not be part of the table view function, you have copied it into a place where it is never called. Move it out and place a break point on it to see that it is being called.